# python getter and setter properties

Tags: python, properties, getter, setter

I am new to properties in Python and a bit confused on how below code is working

```py
class FavoriteShape:
    def __init__(self, color, shape):
        self.color = color
        self.shape = shape

    @property
    def shape(self):
        print('getter method for shape')
        return self.something_else

    @shape.setter
    def shape(self, x):
        print('setter method for shape')
        self.something_else = x

obj1 = FavoriteShape('blue','square')
print('color = ' + obj1.color)
print('shape = ' + obj1.shape)
```

I understand that in the `__init__` function, python calls the setter in the `self.shape` assignment.
But the setter itself is assigning a value , x in this case, to a variable called something_else.
How is the value of this `something_else` is getting assigned to the self.shape ?

I tried googling similar questions and played with Python for some time. I would appreciate anyone's help here.
Thanks a lot !!

Comment: It is not assigned to `self.shape`. But the property getter `self.shape` returns the value of `self.something_else` so it looks like it.

Comment: One comment though to prevent misconceptions: `self.shape` is not an attribute in this case (it is a property). Instead it implicitly calls the getter function.

Comment: if you want a deeper understanding of properties, you might want to start with descriptors: https://realpython.com/python-descriptors/